# R: Counting Overall Percentage of 0's in Data

Tags: r, count, data-manipulation, na

I am working with the R programming language.

In the following link (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-the-percentage-of-missing-values-in-a-dataframe-in-r/), I found out a method to calculate the total percentage of NAs in a data frame :

```
# declaring a data frame in R
data_frame = data.frame(C1= c(1, 2, NA, 0),
                        C2= c( NA, NA, 3, 8), 
                        C3= c("A", "V", "j", "y"),
                        C4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA))
  
percentage = mean(is.na(data_frame)) * 100

[1] 43.75
```

**My Question:** Is there a way to extend this to count the percentage of "any element" in the data frame?

For example, can this be used to calculate the percentage of 0s in the data set? Or the percentage of times "j" appears in the data? Or the percentage of times "2" appears in the data set?

I can do this manually:

```
# count percentage of "j" in the data 

v1 = nrow(subset(data_frame, C1 == "j")) 
v2 = nrow(subset(data_frame, C2 == "j"))
v3 = nrow(subset(data_frame, C3== "j")) 
v4 = nrow(subset(data_frame, C4 == "j"))

percentage = ((v1 + v2 + v3 + v4) / ((nrow(data_frame) * ncol(data_frame)))) * 100

[1] 6.25

# count percentage of "0" in the data  (I don't think this is right, it should be written as "nrow(subset(data_frame, C1 <= 0))"?)

v1 = nrow(subset(data_frame, C1 = 0)) 
v2 = nrow(subset(data_frame, C2 = 0))
v3 = nrow(subset(data_frame, C3= 0)) 
v4 = nrow(subset(data_frame, C4 = 0))

percentage = ((v1 + v2 + v3 + v4) / ((nrow(data_frame) * ncol(data_frame)))) * 100
```

But is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `unlist` your data frame into a vector

```
vec = unlist(data_frame)

mean(vec %in% "j") * 100 # 6.25
mean(vec %in% "0") * 100 # 6.25
mean(vec %in% NA)  * 100 # 43.75
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no embedded lists in the cells of the data frame, you don't have to unlist it:

```r
data_frame = data.frame(C1= c(1, 2, NA, 0),
                         C2= c( NA, NA, 3, 8), 
                         C3= c("A", "V", "j", "y"),
                         C4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA))
 
sum(data_frame == 'j', na.rm = TRUE) / prod(dim(data_frame)) * 100
[1] 6.25

sum(data_frame == 0, na.rm = TRUE) / prod(dim(data_frame)) * 100
[1] 6.25

sum(is.na(data_frame)) / prod(dim(data_frame)) * 100
[1] 43.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` + base R solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_frame %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x %in% "j")) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  mean() * 100
```

Output

```
[1] 6.25
```

Though this could easily be turned into a function.

```
calc <- function(df, val) {
  df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x %in% val)) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    mean() * 100
}
```

Output

```
calc(data_frame, "j") # 6.25
calc(data_frame, "0") # 6.25
calc(data_frame, NA) # 43.75
```

Comment: @ Andrew : Thank you so much for your answer! If you have time, can you please take a look at this question later? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503039/r-assigning-data-to-their-percentiles Thanks!