# R: Assigning Data to their Percentiles

Tags: r, data-manipulation, percentage, quantile

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose, I have the following data frame:

```
var_1 = rnorm(100,10,10)
var_2 = rnorm(100,10,10)
var_3 = rnorm(100,10,10)

d = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3)

head(d)


      var_1     var_2      var_3
1 14.251923 14.877801  22.636207
2  7.325137  8.513718  21.021522
3  3.400001 -3.400397  11.274797
4 16.400597  8.623980   9.366115
5  7.065583 13.155570  17.891432
6 21.297912  4.341385 -11.337330
```

**My Question:** For each element in each variable, I want to replace the element with the percentile (e.g., 5th, 10th, 15th, etc.) it belongs to.

For example:

```
a = quantile(d$var_1, c(0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1))
b = quantile(d$var_2, c(0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1))
c = quantile(d$var_3, c(0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1))

new = data.frame(a,b,c)

              a           b          c
5%   -0.8806901 -7.40560488 -4.7353920
10%   0.3595086 -3.77910527 -0.6874766
15%   1.1201300 -2.91946322  0.9584040
20%   3.0581928  0.05127097  2.1457693
25%   5.0901641  1.91719913  4.6997966
30%   7.0056228  2.56215345  6.2691894
35%   7.6089831  3.58688942  7.1900823
40%   8.9853805  5.00957881  7.8488446
45%   9.9264540  5.73653135  8.6135093
50%  10.2235212  7.43425669  9.6063344
55%  11.5707533  8.54160196 10.9239040
60%  13.2422940  9.65006232 11.7036647
65%  15.1076889 11.07081528 13.2440004
70%  16.5354881 12.38804922 15.2585324
75%  17.9336020 13.16121940 17.6656208
80%  19.5312682 15.31472178 18.4820207
85%  21.9264905 17.99689941 19.3347983
90%  24.4511364 20.47478783 22.0647173
95%  26.6820271 25.27082341 24.4473033
100% 41.4419744 39.75848302 34.5105183
```

Now, each time a variable is between each percentile range, I would like to make the following replacement:

- if `d$var_1 < -0.8806901`, then `d$var_1 == as.factor("5th percentile")`
- if `d$var_1 > -0.8806901 d$var_1 <  0.3595086`, then `d$var_1 == as.factor("10th percentile")`

...

- if `d$var_1 > 15.1076889 d$var_1 <   16.5354881`, then `d$var_1 == as.factor("65th percentile")`

etc.

- if `d$var_2  < -7.40560488`, then `d$var_2 == as.factor("5th percentile")`

etc.

- if `d$var_3 < -4.7353920`, then `d$var_3 == as.factor("5th percentile")`

etc.

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you want

```
apply(d, 2, function(x) paste0( ntile(x, n = 20L) / 20 * 100, "th percentile" ))
```

output

```
       var_1              var_2              var_3             
  [1,] "60th percentile"  "100th percentile" "25th percentile" 
  [2,] "80th percentile"  "60th percentile"  "100th percentile"
  [3,] "45th percentile"  "90th percentile"  "75th percentile" 
  [4,] "70th percentile"  "85th percentile"  "35th percentile" 
  [5,] "30th percentile"  "5th percentile"   "55th percentile" 
  ...
```

Completment

```
library(data.table)
cols = c("var_1", "var_3")
setDT(d)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0( ntile(x, n = 20L) / 20 * 100, "th percentile")), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: @ Peace Wang: Thank you so much for your answer! I made a slight modification to your code : final_data = data.frame(apply(d, 2, function(x) paste0( ntile(x, n = 20L) / 20 * 100, "th percentile" )))

Comment: My only question is - can this be done directly from the "new" data frame I had created?

Comment: For example, what if there were uneven quantiles? for example: a = quantile(d$var_1, c(0.05, 0.16, 0.23, 0.61, 0.82, 0.98)) ; b = quantile(d$var_2, c(0.09, 0.26, 0.33, 0.55, 0.91)) ;  c = quantile(d$var_3, c(0.19, 0.51, 0.87))

Comment: `ntile(x , n = 20L)`  provide a rough rank to avoid compare.  For uneven quantiles, it is needed to check whether the relation with  `ntile` still hold or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Another question - suppose I just wanted to make replacements for column 1 and column 3. Is something like this possible? final_data = data.frame(apply(d[,c(1,3), 2, function(x) paste0( ntile(x, n = 20L) / 20 * 100, "th percentile" )))

Comment: `apply` will not change value of `d`,  `lapply` maybe useful.

Comment: do you mean like this? lapply(d[,c(1,3)], 2, function(x) paste0( ntile(x, n = 20L) / 20 * 100, "th percentile" ))

Comment: If you  just wanted to make replacements for column 1 and column 3, see the complement part in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an almost one-liner with my `santoku` package:

```r
library(santoku)
d[] <- apply(d, 2, chop_quantiles, probs = 0:100/100, 
               labels = lbl_endpoint(fmt = "%.2f"))
d[] <- apply(d, 2, as.numeric)
```

The `d[]` on the left hand side is a trick to keep `d` as a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `purrr` here (thanks @PeaceWang for the function).

```
library(tidyverse)

output <- purrr::map(d, function(x)
  paste0(ntile(x, n = 20L) / 20 * 100, "th percentile")) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Output

```
head(output, 10)

               var_1            var_2            var_3
1    40th percentile  15th percentile  85th percentile
2     5th percentile  60th percentile  70th percentile
3    65th percentile  60th percentile  65th percentile
4    60th percentile  10th percentile  75th percentile
5    15th percentile  40th percentile   5th percentile
6    10th percentile  35th percentile  85th percentile
7    30th percentile  45th percentile  95th percentile
8    85th percentile  25th percentile  45th percentile
9    75th percentile  90th percentile  80th percentile
10   65th percentile 100th percentile  10th percentile
```

Comment: @ Andrew: Thank you so much for your answer! I used "even and consistent" percentiles to make my question easier to answer - but what if the percentiles were uneven?

Comment: For example, what if: a = quantile(d$var_1, c(0.05, 0.16, 0.23, 0.61, 0.82, 0.98)) ; b = quantile(d$var_2, c(0.09, 0.26, 0.33, 0.55, 0.91)) ; c = quantile(d$var_3, c(0.19, 0.51, 0.87))

Comment: Is there a "match" function in R that can replace every element in a column in one data frame, with a pre-defined list of other elements in another data frame?

Comment: Just something I realized - you can decide which columns you want to replace! Here, you can make the replacements only on the first and third column: output <- purrr::map(d[,c(1,3)], function(x)
  paste0(ntile(x, n = 20L) / 20 * 100, "th percentile")) %>%
  as.data.frame()